# Jquery conflict with other script

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I have 2 script of jquery and with firebug i see exists conflict between both

The Script with create error it´s this :

```
<script>
$(function () {
    $("#header_background_night_star").stars({
        "i": "<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/images/star.png",
    });
});    
</script>
```

**And FireBug show this error:**

```
TypeError: $ is not a function
```

I try create anonyme function for jquery but no works me and tell me the function no writte right , if i don´t put the until function the other script works fine but if i put this code the function no works

Regards and thank´s for the help

Comment: Use [jQuery.noConflict()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(function($){

//put your code here

})(jQuery)

//The above function is restrict the $ character to this particular function scope, and that //$ not conflict with any other plugins on you page.

see the below url

http://7elab.com/jquery/jquery-conflict-with-prototype/

Comment: Also i can no put "$" and put jQuery ?

Comment: inside that function you can use $ because as a argument you assign jQuery object alias ($), you can assign whatever you want to use, instead of $!

Comment: You can use jQuery instead of $ inside the scope function!.

Answer (score 3):

If `$` is not a function, it would appear that you haven't included jQuery at all. If there was an actual conflict, I'd expect `$` to be a non-jQuery-function.

Comment: I include jquery if no include jquery other scripts no work me and the conflict it´s with the plugin called revo slider , this slider no work me because create conflict with the function i put in the post and if i delete this all works fine and other scripts also , the problem it´s only with this little function , thsnk´s

Comment: Do you have a link to the page producing the error? Revo slider, from what I can find, is a jQuery plugin and shouldn't cause conflicts.

Answer (score 0):

Use "jQuery"  instead of "$" and one more thing check you added jquery file

```
    <script>
jQuery(function () {
    jQuery("#header_background_night_star").stars({
        "i": "<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/images/star.png",
    });
});    
</script>
```